# “Bonsoir” or “Bonne soirée”?

Tags: sens, usage, choix-de-mot, salutations

I have a small doubt regarding the usage of *Bon soir* and *Bonne soirée*. 
As far as my understanding goes or you can blindly say what I have been doing till now is: *Bon soir*, when you meet someone and *Bonne soirée* when you take leave of the same person(s).

I had a situation recently.So when I begin, I go by a *salut* in the morning and a *salut* when I leave for home in the evening. Yesterday, for a change I tried *Bonne soirée* while leaving and the replies as expected were *ciao*, *salut*… and some unexpected  *Bon soir*'s. So this confused me a bit!

Should I have used *Bon soir* or *Bonne soirée*?

---

Related queries:

While on the way back home if I meet someone whom I had already greeted in the morning, what should be the greeting in the context of *Bon soir* or *Bonne soirée* (no actual conversations involved except the greeting)?

What is the factor (time or sunlight) for switching from *Bonjour* or *Bonne journée* to *Bon soir* or *Bonne soirée*?

Combinations: *Merci*  *Bonne journée*  *Au revoir* ; Is this combination acceptable or should  *Bonne journée* be the last in the list. Example situation: while leaving a *magasin* or a *bus*.

Comment: You could start from [this page](http://culturefrancaise.over-blog.com/article-bonjour-bonsoir-bonne-journee-au-revoir-51911205.html). Not forgetting that there are [regional variations](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour). Et [en Suisse](http://claweb.cla.unipd.it/home/smazurelle/dynamots/a1/m1/suisse_transcript.htm)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's not a question, in fact, but many.

First of all, **that's *Bonsoir* in one word, not *Bon soir***. But indeed, the general principle you quote at start is mainly correct (meeting/taking leave of someone).

For the confusion you had with people responding with *Bonsoir* when you left, although it's probably rarer than *Bonne soirée*, it's possible also. The only "too odd" usage would be *Bonne soirée* when meeting someone you're going to spend the evening with. Saying *Bonsoir* when leaving is acceptable, though more formal than the other alternatives you quoted (*Ciao*, *Salut*).

When meeting someone on the way back home (but no actual conversation intended beyond simple greetings), use *Bonsoir* any time, but *Bonne soirée* if (and only if) you can suppose your interlocutor hasn't actually finished his *soirée* (in other words, if you somehow know he's going home to sleep, in case you should use *Bonne nuit*). And, in a way, it makes sense: it would be pretty absurd to wish someone an event in the past. Following this rule, you "can" (and should ! friendliness is a nice thing...) certainly say *Bonne soirée* to someone on his way back home, if he just mentioned he's having a party at home for his birthday for example. And of course, you cannot say it if he just said *Je n'en peux plus, je rentre me coucher.*

> In other words, using *Bonne soirée* (or *Bonne journée*) has in fact more to do with your interlocutor's activity than it has to do with time or sunlight. Use a neutral *Bonsoir* when you don't know.

For your last question, *Merci, bonne journée, au revoir* sounds (to me) redundant (symbolically if not technically) and is slightly too "heavy". *Merci et au revoir !* or *Merci, bonne journée !* sound best if I may.)

Comment: What about _Bonne fin de soirée_ ?

Comment: @mouviciel Excellent \*other\* question ;-) Let's say it stands between *Bonne soirée* and *Bonne nuit*... though probably closer to the latter.

Comment: ***Bon soir***,  il faut remonter au temps de Voltaire pour le voir écrit souvent comme cela ! De nos jours sur scène, le théâtre aime bien jouer sur ces nuances-là pour  *insister*, ce n’est plus une formule de politesse *[« Allez, Bonne soirée » et en aparté « Que le diable l’emporte …»]*, mais une marque d’attention à l’autre… le contraire des selfies :-)

Comment: disagree, Bonne Soiree is used when you wish someone to have a good time if they have plans to do something fun. Bonsoir is just a standard goodbye/good evening when you leave someone or go home for the evening

Comment: @opale What's the disagreement about? I agree with your (succinct) definitions.

Answer (score 13):

- *Bonsoir* pour *au revoir* lorsque l'on se quitte en fin l'après midi ou juste avant la nuit.
- *Bonsoir* peut se dire aussi lorsque l'on arrive dans une assemblée aux mêmes horaires, plutôt qu'un tardif *bonjour*.
- *Bonne soirée*  sous-entend : *passez une bonne soirée* (en général lorsque quelqu'un a l'intention de passer la soirée en dehors de son domicile) si l'on quitte quelqu'un, ou que ce dernier s'en va.

*Précision :*

- *Bonsoir* s'écrit en un seul mot lorsqu'il s'agit d'une locution.
- *Bon soir* désigne une fin de journée particulière :
   Vous allez au théâtre ? Que ce soit un *bon soir* pour vous !

Answer (score 2):

bonjour, bonsoir are greetings
bonne journée, bonne soirée mean have a nice day, have a nice evening.

A native French speaker would never say:
"Vous allez au théâtre? Que ce soit un bon soir pour vous!"
Instead you could say: "Vous allez au théâtre? Passez UNE BONNE SOIREE!

reference: pages 223 to 227 Le Français déchiffré, clé du langage et des langues
Henri Adamcweski

Comment: Ce n’est pas avec les livres que j’ai formulé ma réponse, mais pour l’avoir entendue … et souvent pour insister : "*Bonsoir*, et que ce soit un *bon soir* pour toi [là où tu vas] ; pour moi, le mot *never* n’est pas de mise,

Answer (score 1):

"Bonsoir" is standard and can be used when you arrive somewhere (in the evening) and when you leave (in the evening).

On the other hand "Bonne soirée" is a little bit more involved and can be used as a goodbye wish when you leave. I have always felt that there is something unpleasant and intrusive in the "Bonne soirée" wish. Why on earth do you need to wish a good evening to somebody when you leave : it seems to mean "Now that I am leaving, I sincerely wish that the remaining part of the evening will be nicer for you". It carries some elements of bitterness and dissatisfaction.

Comment: *Bonne soirée* ne signifie pas *Meilleure soirée sans moi*. Je ne vois pas pourquoi souhaiter une *bonne soirée* serait moins sincère que *bon voyage*, *bonne nuit* ou *bon appétit*.

Comment: Agreed with jiliagre, this negative/ironic subtext you're describing is quite odd to me. Irony can be the underlying intent of *any* positive wish, by definition. I guess it's a subjective thing.